# How are aliens affected by darkness in OpenXCom

Tags: open-xcom

During night missions, the range in which aliens can be spotted depends on the light conditions of the tile they are standing on. Does the illumination around my soldiers also allow the aliens to spot them, making the night penalty effectively not applicable to them? What about other light sources like fire, EM flares or light sources which occur on the map? Should I avoid placing soldiers near them or do they have no effect on the ability of aliens to spot my soldiers?

Comment: Is OpenXCom actually a separate game? Or just a different way to play the original?

Comment: @frank seems like it is a clone of the original. But there are also mods to change things.

Comment: @Frank It is a clone which tries to be as close to the original as possible. But considering that the game was reprogrammed from scratch and not build with the input of the original developers, there is no guarantee that all game mechanics are 100% identical to the original, especially those which are hard to observe like this one.

Comment: I was a bit hasty (and tired) when I changed the tags, but OpenXCOM is an attempt to be 100% accurate to the known game mechanics in XCOM, which means, for the majority of game mechanic questions, the answers will be the same.  Either tag is fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [more detailed answer](http://ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Night_Missions) is available in the UFOpaedia.

The short version is they aren't. Aliens always see out to 20 squares, but X-Com operatives' range of vision is reduced to 9 during nighttime. Thus, positioning your soldiers near flares and street lamps will not give the aliens any advantage they didn't already have.

OpenXCom doesn't alter most rules of the original game unless you tell it to. By default, lines of sight shouldn't be any different.